# MVC Membership and RC 1.0?

Tags: model-view-controller, membership

Does the project - https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit - work with the latest release of RC 1.0 ?

Does anyone know whether its been upgraded or ? i.e. seems the source hasn't been upgraded in a while and I thought it was being actively developed?

Just wondering if anyone has implemented it, got it working - cares to update the source (i would but im new to MVC and have no idea what existed in previous releases and 1.0)?

Any ideas / help ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered emailing the author?  There's an email link on the home page.

Comment: hey! thanks for the response. yeah I have - but no love ? It seems many people are downloading it - but there are a bunch of comments suggesting it doesnt work ?

Just wondering if anyone has successfully implemented it ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you just try downloading the code and checking the MVC DLL bundled with it?

I did just that and found the version on System.Web.Mvc.dll is 1.0.40112.0.  I believe this version is either RC1 or Beta.

Comment: Hey thanks pete - yeah I'm quite new to MVC - so was loving this project when i found it but im learning via MVC 1.0 - so I have no idea whats changed between previous iterations and 1.0 ?

Comment: I started with ASP.Net MVC Preview 3 and I would say the most major changes came between Preview 3 and 4.  Since then, ASP.Net MVC runtime hasn't changed all that much -- especially since the Beta release.  The tooling for MVC within Visual Studio has seen the most change in recent releases.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it yet. However, very little has changed between the MVC RC2 and release versions. I have an MVC app I started building during RC1, and it wasn't affected by either RC2 or v1.0

Read up on the v1.0 release notes for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It was updated on Aug 7 2009 to work with MVC 1.0